# Cross-browser margin

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, margin

The "Picture" tab on my site has a 1px overflow in Firefox, as shown below:

[image: picture]

As you can see the border lines on the sides are a bit past the horizontal line. However, the Picture tab is positioned perfectly in Chrome. I searched and found out that the issue is due to browsers rendering margins differently, but I'm not sure how I can solve it?

Here's the css for the tab

```
<div style="position:absolute;
margin-top:-38px;
margin-left:370px;
font-size:20px;
padding:6px;
border-left:1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
border-right:1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
border-top:1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
background-color:white;"></div>
```

And here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hmrq/1/), try to open it with Chrome and FF

Comment: There needs to be enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The fiddle looks normal to me?  Also, your code needs to be in the question, as jsfiddle is frequently slow/down.

Comment: On both FF and Chrome?

Comment: Yes, both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Are you using a css reset ?

Answer (score 0):

Like you already know each browser has it's own predefined styling to certain elements, in order to have everything working the same in all browsers you need to use a **[css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**.

The css reset sets the margins,padding and most of the predefined styling back to 0 so you don't get any surprises.

The code so the answer remains valid if the article is taken down.

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```